# How to use a function as data with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

To reduce duplicated script, I created the following plugin, and it works as long as `data` is left as is.

```
$.fn.myValid = function(rules, options) {
    this.validate({
        rules: rules.rules,
        messages: rules.messages,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var o = Object.assign({},{
                type:'POST',
                url:null,
                data: $(form).serializeArray(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (rsp){
                    //Instead of reloading page, do dynamicly
                    $.unblockUI();
                    alert('record submitted')
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    alert(xhr.responseJSON.message);
                }
                }, options);
            //if (typeof o.data === "function") o.data=o.data(form);
            $.blockUI();
            $.ajax(o);
        }
    });
};
```

If `data` needs to be changed, I cannot simply return something like `$(form).serializeArray().concat($('#common-inputs').serializeArray(form))` because `form` is not yet defined, so instead I thought returning a function would work.  When ajax is fired, however, `data` is a function, and not a string, array, or plain object, so data is not sent to the server.

```
$('#help-form').myValid(validObj.common, {url:'ajax.php','data': function(form){
    console.log('this is never executed);
    return $(form).serializeArray().concat($('#common-inputs').serializeArray(form))
}});
```

As a workaround, I included `o.data=o.data(form);` (is commented out in above script) to execute the function to return results, and it works as desired.  I expect, however, it is more of a hack, and there is a correct way to do this.

What is the proper way to use a function as data with jQuery ajax?

Will the solution be different for other properties such as `url`, `success`, etc?

Comment: As a solution for me I've done the following: I have a custom ajax wrapper and at the callback an object with functions to execute but I don't send the function, I have the functions defined in the App object and just send them as strings and evaluate them in the success event using the `apply` function.

I have a github with the wrapper, It's a little outdated but I think you can see the ideea. Maybe you can apply the logic to your plugin https://github.com/sabbin/JQPS-Framework

Comment: @Sabbin  Thanks for your suggestion.  Yes, I see how this could work, but feel there should be a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **beforeSend** callback to set the **data** value:

```
beforeSend: function( xhr, settings ) {
    this.data = $(form).serialize(); // or settings.data = $(form).serialize();
},
```

Same way you can modify url and success callbacks:

```
this.url = 'new-url';
this.success = newSuccessCallback;
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881982/how-to-modify-the-ajax-post-data-in-a-beforesend-event)

Note this does not work for GET requests, but POST should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your first question:
What is the proper way to use a function as data with jQuery ajax?

Function can be used to create any type of data as long as you are going to return the data in the function call. As with jquery ajax, this would be a callback function and you call it whenever you need it.

```
# Example

function formData( form ) {
    // do anything
    return form.serialize();
}

var request = $.ajax({
    // set properties
    data: formData.call( context, form );
});
```

Will the solution be different for other properties such as url, success, etc?

For the success callback, use the .done() method or .fail() method for error

And url:

```
function getFormURL( form ) {
    return form.attr('action');
}
```

url: getFormURL.call( context, .form );

Answer (score 0):

If you are to want to pass a dynamic parameters to remote api , the code as follows

```
$.ajax({
    uri: '/foo',
    ...,
    data: function() {
        param1: function() {
            return 'foo';
        },
        param2: function() {
            return $('input[name='bar']').val();
        }
    }
})
```